# Expand data.frame by adding new column

Tags: r, dataframe, expand

Here an example of my data.frame(s):

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1871:1872))
df2 = data.frame(y=c(1:3))
```

How can I expand `df` with `df2` observations?

Desired output:

```
x     y
1871  1
1871  2
1871  3
1872  1
1872  2
1872  3
```

I couldn't find any solution yet.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way with `lapply`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df$x, function(z) {
  cbind(z, df2)
}))
#     z y
#1 1871 1
#2 1871 2
#3 1871 3
#4 1872 1
#5 1872 2
#6 1872 3
```

`lapply` iterates over `df$x` and `cbind`s the whole `df2` to each element of `df$x`. `do.call` combines everything together in one data.frame.

Comment: A tidyr option would be `expand(df, x, y = df2$y)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun . Maybe post as an answer?

Comment: It is almost similar to the answer given here.  So, i thought to comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A solution using `expand.grid` that gives you all combinations of two variables.

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1871:1872))
df2 = data.frame(y=c(1:3))

expand.grid(x = df$x, y = df2$y)

#      x y
# 1 1871 1
# 2 1872 1
# 3 1871 2
# 4 1872 2
# 5 1871 3
# 6 1872 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A third (but less elegant) solution:

```
data.frame(x=rep(df$x, each=nrow(df2)), 
           y=rep(df2$y,length(unique(df$x)))
)

#      x y
# 1 1871 1
# 2 1871 2
# 3 1871 3
# 4 1872 1
# 5 1872 2
# 6 1872 3
```